# Using the Parity or Geth light client, how can I monitor an address for transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, parity, pending-transactions, light-clients

I'd like to use Parity or Geth, in light client mode, to monitor an address for transactions.  Essentially, I should be able to check each block for transactions involving a certain address.

In the end, the goal is to have devices linked to wallet addresses.  Payments can be made to these addresses to launch software containers or other software on the devices.

Thanks so much for any help, tips, or pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In Web3.js 1.0, they offer the ability to subscribe to events using WebSockets:

http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html

To get started you can check out this [tutorial I made](https://shawntabrizi.com/ethereum/using-web3-js-1-0-subscribe-and-infura-websockets-to-visualize-ethereum-transactions/) which uses [Infura](https://infura.io/) as my WebSocket provider.

Parity will, [by default](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum#about-parity-ethereum), set up a WebSockets server on `127.0.0.1:8546`.

Geth uses the same endpoint, but you also need to make sure to [use the `--ws*` flags](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#programatically-interfacing-geth-nodes) to enable the WS-RPC.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try this out.